# Aplicar maskMoney em campos adicionados dinamicamente

Tags: maskmoney

Tenho um formulário onde eu adiciono `valor`, `data`, `detalhes_transacao`, porém, estes campos são adicionados dinamicamente através de um javascript.
O problema é que a máscara de valor (maskMoney) funciona somente no primeiro campo, que está visível na tela... quando os campos são adicionados dinamicamente, não funciona.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="debit-after">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money" id="debit[0][amount]" name="debit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control border-input" id="debit[0][ddate]" name="debit[0][ddate]" placeholder="Date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Details</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit[0][details]" name="debit[0][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-1" id='debit-transaction-lasted'>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="debit-transaction"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-add"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Transactions Debit
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#debit-after"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".debit-transaction-edit"); //Add button ID
    var total_debit    = $("#debit_total_rows").val();


    var x = total_debit; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="debit['+ x +'][amount]" name="debit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="debit['+ x +'][ddate]" name="debit['+ x +'][ddate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit['+ x +'][details]" name="debit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_debit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Class que eu aplico para valores: `money`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.money').maskMoney();
});
```

Resultado em Tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi porque me negativaram, podem explicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O problema é que, quando você adiciona somente
>   `$('.money').maskMoney();`, no início, ele só funciona para os elementos que são carregados na atualização da página. Então, para resolver esse problema, você deve, em todas as vezes que adicionar um novo elemento que contenha uma **máscara**, a
>   função do plugin, que é o `$('.money').maskMoney();`.

Eu fiz umas edições no seu código para ficar mais fácil, entretanto, não tira a essência do problema que você estava enfrentando.

> **O problema está resolvido.**

```js
// Transactions Debit
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.money').maskMoney();
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#debit-after"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".debit-transaction-edit"); //Add button ID
    var total_debit    = $("#debit_total_rows").val();


    var x = total_debit; //initlal text box count
    
    add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        
        e.preventDefault();
   ++x;
            $(wrapper).append('<hr/><div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="debit['+ x +'][amount]" name="debit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="debit['+ x +'][ddate]" name="debit['+ x +'][ddate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit['+ x +'][details]" name="debit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div><hr/>'); //add input box
            
            document.getElementById("debit["+ x +"][amount]").focus();
            
            $('.money').maskMoney();

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field_debit_edit", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group" id="debit-after">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-input money" id="debit[0][amount]" name="debit[0][amount]" placeholder="Amount" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control border-input" id="debit[0][ddate]" name="debit[0][ddate]" placeholder="Date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Details</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit[0][details]" name="debit[0][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-1" id='debit-transaction-lasted'>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="debit-transaction"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-add"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="debit-transaction-edit">Add</button>
```

> Adicione o código: `$('.money').maskMoney();` todas as vezes que
>   você adicionar um novo campo.

```
 if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="note"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input money" placeholder="Amount" value="" id="debit['+ x +'][amount]" name="debit['+ x +'][amount]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><input type="date" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Date" id="debit['+ x +'][ddate]" name="debit['+ x +'][ddate]"></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="debit['+ x +'][details]" name="debit['+ x +'][details]" placeholder="Details of Transaction"></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field_debit_edit"><i class="fa fa-trash icon-trash"></i></a></div></div></div><div>'); //add input box

         //Adicione este fragmento de código:
         $('.money').maskMoney();

        }
```

Comment: Só para teste, ao clicar nele, são adicionados os campos que você deseja.

Comment: Funcionou como deveria, muito obrigado.